# Removing an element from python string recursively?

Tags: python, string, recursion

I'm trying to figure out how to write a program that would remove a given element from a python string recursively. Here's what I have so far:

```
def remove(x,s):
    if x == s[0]:
        return ''
    else:
        return s[0] + remove(x,s[1:])
```

When testing this code on the input remove('t', 'wait a minute'), it seems to work up until it reaches the first 't', but the code then terminates instead of continuing to go through the string. Does anyone have any ideas of how to fix this?

Comment: Typo. Should say remove(x, s[1:]) in the recursive call

Comment: Are you using python 2.x ?

Comment: `return s[0] + remove(x, s[1:]) if s[0] != x else remove(x,s[1:])` with an `if not s:return ""` at the start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, you return `''` when you run into the character you're removing.
This will drop the rest of the string.

You want to keep going through the string instead (also pass `x` in recursive calls and add a base case):

```
def remove(x, s):
    if not s:
        return ''
    if x == s[0]:
        return remove(x, s[1:])
    else:
        return s[0] + remove(x, s[1:])
```

Also, in case you didn't know, you can use `str.replace()` to achieve this:

```
>>> 'wait a minute'.replace('t', '')
'wai a minue'
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: The  `''` is redundant in   `return '' + remove(x, s[1:])`, you also don't need the else

Comment: You're right, I was more focused on fixing the OP's code than making sense. I prefer to have the `else` there, just for added clarity.

Answer (score 0):

```
def Remove(s,e):
    return filter(lambda x: x!= e, s)
```

Here is  an example for your test

```
sequence = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
RemoveElement = ['d','c']
print(filter(lambda x: x not in RemoveElement, sequence))

#['a', 'b', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are just replacing/removing a character like 't' you could just use a list comprehension:

```
s = 'wait a minute'
xs = ''.join(x for x in s if x != 't')
```